# Exponentials of the roots of polynomials $P(x)$ are always the roots of $P^*(x)?$

Tags: polynomials, roots

> For any polynomial $P(x)$ with rational coefficients and no constant terms, are the exponentials of the roots of $P(x)=c_1x^n+c_2x^{n-1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot~+ c_kx$ always equal to the roots of $P^*(x)=e^{c_1\log^n(x)}+e^{c_2\log^{n-1}(x)}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot~+c_kx?$

There's probably an obvious way to see this but I haven't been able to find a proof. I've tried calculating many examples and so far I haven't found any counter-examples. For example I calculated that $p(x)=x^2-x^3$ has roots @ $x=0,1$ and $p^*(x)=e^{\log^2(x)}-e^{\log^3(x)}$ has roots @ $x=1,e.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $P(x)=x$, we get $P^{*}(x)=x$. Note that $0$ is a root of $P$ but $e^{0}=1$ is not a root of $P^{*}$.

Another example: $P(x)=x+x^{2}$. the roots are $0$ and $-1$. But $e^{-1}$ is  not  a root of $P^{*}$ in this case.

In your example the calculation of $P^{*}$ is wrong. The minus sign goes to the exponent.

Comment: I'm going to change the question to add that $P(x)$ must have at least two terms

Comment: @geocalc33 I think your claim fails in most cases.

Comment: do you know why it occurs for the example I gave?

Comment: @geocalc33 See my answer.

Comment: no it's not wrong, that's the convention

Comment: @geocalc33 According to your definition the second term is $e^{(-1) (\log x)^{3}}$ and not $(-1) e^{ (\log x)^{3}}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111477/discussion-between-geocalc33-and-kavi-rama-murthy).